# Semantic-UI: Auto-Install using default folders instead of folders stored in semantic.json file

Tags: continuous-integration, symfony, semantic-ui

I'm trying to set up the continuous integration process for a Symfony project that we use Semantic UI in. Unfortunately, our attempts so far to get the correct folder structure have repeatedly failed in various inconsistent ways including getting different results from the same semantic.json file.

Here is the current project folder structure:

```
\app    // Symfony app config
\bin    // Composer dependency scripts
\docker // Docker config
\spec   // PHP Spec and Unit tests
\src    // Symfony bundles
\vendor // Composer packages
\web    // Publicly accessible root
```

What we want to do is set up Semantic-UI to place the scripts for the build process in `\semantic` and then build to `\web\scripts\semantic`. We already have node, npm and gulp set up on the development machine and the makefile will run `gulp build` before building the Docker image so that all changes end up on the image. We installed Semantic-UI manually through npm first, saving to the package.json file, configuring the folders we could through the custom install method. However, this doesn't configure all the folders and leaves some in their default locations. We modified the semantic.json files to the following:

```
{
  "base": "/",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "semantic/theme.config",
      "definitions": "semantic/definitions/",
      "site": "semantic/site/",
      "themes": "semantic/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "web/scripts/semantic/",
      "uncompressed": "web/scripts/semantic/components/",
      "compressed": "web/scripts/semantic/components/",
      "themes": "web/scripts/semantic/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "web/scripts/semantic/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": false,
  "rtl": false,
  "components": [
    ...  // skiping all the component entries
  ],
  "version": "2.2.7"
}
```

Then deleted the folders created by the first install and ran `npm install`, however this just wanted to rewrite the existing config and install back to the default folders. We tried enabling auto-install and it didn't create most of the folders at all which meant the gulp build process would fail.

Is there anyone with some experience of Semantic who might be able to shed light onto what we need to do to achieve the project structure we desire for this and it still work for continuous integration?